# How to get Libdmtx (specifically dmtxread from dmtx-utils) running on windows (PHP)

Tags: php, datamatrix

I have built a PHP based system that decodes Datamatrix barcodes from production images, then correctly files those images and catalogues the details to a DB for ease of reference and recall.

This uses the **dmtxread** utility from [Libdmtx](https://github.com/dmtx), and works well on a Linux server (I had to do a fresh build of [dmtx-utils](https://github.com/dmtx/dmtx-utils) as the PHPize of the [php-dmtx](https://github.com/dmtx/php-dmtx) PHP bindings would not work from the EPEL install).

This system has to decode multiple images per second, and dmtx is BY FAR the fastest and most accurate Datamatrix utility I have found so far - even though it hasn't seen any development in quite a few years.

My issue is, that for one particular purpose, I need to have it running on a Windows server but I cannot figure out how to achieve this.

I cannot find any reference of dmxt-utils working on a windows server, beyond producing a DLL - which I have done using Cygwin. However, I have no idea what to with the DLL to get it working, or how to make it available to PHP.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Use docker or vagrant ?

Comment: Yeah, I am using the system in Docker atm. It works, but I want to get it all 'under one roof' as there seems to be an overhead with Docker mapping and moving the files about, that is not apparent on the built in web server. It is only tiny but with the huge volumes of images, it makes a big difference overall.